# Azure web application crashes after config change or swap and stays down for hours

Tags: asp.net, azure, web-applications, deployment, crash

Since we moved the majority of our users to our asp.net web application running as a web application in Azure we've experienced an intermittent issue where the application will crash for all users, responding only with time-outs or 502/503 errors. This is usually occurring after we've made a configuration change (like changing an app setting in the portal) or swapping slots during a deployment. The very frustrating thing is that there appears to be no way to get it back until it eventually sorts itself out. During and immediately before the outage the diagnostics look fine - minimal CPU and memory usage. Lots of errors but they're most timeout errors. This problem is not resolve by scaling out or up, application restarts have no effect. Even killing the w3wp does not bring the app back. CPU profiles taken during outage show failed requests but not much else.

Does anyone know what might be going on here or have any ideas of what we could try?

Comment: Any process now?

Comment: I've installed the extension. Just waiting for the issue to happen again in our production environment. Further info... the issue appears to happen whenever the app is recycled during a period of heavy use.

Comment: We had a significant outage today and I was able to run the CrashDiag site extension. I'm not certain that it was running on an instance that was suffering with the problem (we'd scaled to 4 instance), but it did capture some crash dumps. In all dumps there was the same error. Am I correct that this error actually crashed the worker process? Because the code that throws it is actually handled by a try... catch statement and isn't a particularly unusual error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While running Customer’s .NET processes in Azure Web App environment, it may intermittently crashes due to code or performance issues. It’s important to capture the crash dump when such crash/exception happen automatically for further investigation.

Here is a `CrashDiag Site Extension`, which can easily help us to capture the necessary data when intermittent unhandled exception happens. To capture dump for exceptions, you could refer to this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2015/12/28/use-crash-diagnoser-site-extension-to-capture-dump-for-intermittent-exception-issues-or-performance-issues-on-azure-web-app/).

And as you have said, you only get error message with timeout or 502/503, here is an [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-http-502-http-503) you could refer to troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was actually being caused by our ORM writing to the TraceWriter. A configuration flag had been left on in the production environment due to a change in the deployment process. The TraceWriter is thread safe so was creating locks and blocking the CPU. Busy usage periods would cause requests to the TraceWriter to start queuing, thus leading to a non-responsive application.